# Read windows start time for Win7 and Win10 via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I am able to read the start time from my Win7 computer.

```
public static DateTime WindowsStartTime()
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();

    try
    {
        dt = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, System.Environment.TickCount);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code is not working on Win10 computer.
Does someone have an idea why this is not working ?

Comment: `code is not working` - that is very informative exception details...

Comment: works fine on my windows 10

Comment: Changing your catch block like the following may could help :   catch (Exception ex) {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since [System.Environment.TickCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.7.2) is of type `int` it has maximum value

```
 int.MaxValue = 2147483647 // milliseconds
```

which is

```
 2147483647 ms = 
 2147483.647 seconds ~ 
 24.85 days
```

so if you switched on your workstation about a *month ago or earlier* you'll get wrong time because of *integer overflow* (not *Windows version*)

Comment: if that is the issue kudos for thinking outside the box! Also, some people dont turn off their pc for over a month???

Comment: @DenisSchaf This behavior is well explained in the Remarks section of the [Environment.​Tick​Count Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.7.2) page.

Comment: i still wouldnt have thought of it, as the question did not define "this code is not working" @Clemens